# Which version of sdk and .NET come together with visual studio express c# 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am helping s.o. out over mail to start with c#, and I would like to recommend VS express for it (from [this](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/) link)

It's not clear to me which version of .NET ships with it, and if there will be an SDK with a commandline compiler (cs.exe)..

I am using VS2008 and not too keen to test it all on my system.

tx!

Comment: I hate to say it, but the selected answer is wrong. C# Express ships with 3.5 SP1, including .NET SP2, etc...

Comment: mmm, damn, :) can anyone provide an official link here?

Comment: Well, you can see "Now with Service Pack 1" all over: http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/#webInstall

Comment: BTW - you can install side-by-side with VS2008; I use VSTS for "real" work, and Express as a scratch pad for examples etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line compiler is part of the standard .NET framework.

Express 2005 has been retired, AFAIK. The current C# express download is 2008 Express with Service Pack 1, which includes:

- .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (and all previous service packs, such as 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP1, etc)
- Visual C# Express 2008 SP1

Comment: Since there's no opposition from Jared, I believe you on your word, and accept this-one.  Tx to you both

Answer (score 2):

VS 2008 Express any language has the following .Net Versions

- .Net 2.0 SP1
- .Net 3.5

The .Net SDK will be included with the install.  For the C# version, it will include the 3.0 C# language compiler.  The 2.0 version will also be available in the 2.0 install directory.

Comment: @Marc, I actually meant to type Express myself, must have gotten mixed up :)

Answer (score 0):

For a very extensive description of the differences between all of the Visual Studio products, take a peak at the feature comparison chart here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/vstudio/products/cc149003(en-us).aspx